# ListView.getTag() return null

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview. There is two kind of viewholder inside it and I use `setTag(int key,object tag)` to put it into convertview. But when I invoke `getTag(int key)` to get the holder back, then return null. The code is like this:

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        HistoryViewHolder holder = null;
        HistoryMoreViewHolder moreHolder = null;
        if (view == null  ) {
            if (getItemViewType(i) == item_type_goin) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(InputSearchActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.truck_route_history_item_more, viewGroup, false);
                moreHolder = new HistoryMoreViewHolder();
                moreHolder.tv_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                moreHolder.tv_location = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);
                moreHolder.ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll);
                view.setTag(R.id.history_first_item, moreHolder);
            } else {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(InputSearchActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.truck_route_history_item, viewGroup, false);
                holder = new HistoryViewHolder();
                holder.tv_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
                view.setTag(R.id.history_second_item, holder);
            }
        } else {
            if (getItemViewType(i) == item_type_goin) {
                moreHolder = (HistoryMoreViewHolder) view.getTag(R.id.history_first_item);
                LogUtil.d(moreHolder + ":moreHolder");
            } else {
                holder = (HistoryViewHolder) view.getTag(R.id.history_second_item);
            }
        }
        if (getItemViewType(i) == item_type_goin) {
            moreHolder.tv_location.setText(saveLocations.get(i).getLocation());
            moreHolder.tv_name.setText(saveLocations.get(i).getName());
        } else {
            holder.tv_name.setText(saveLocations.get(i).getName());
        }

        return view;
    }
}

class HistoryViewHolder {
    TextView tv_name;
}

class HistoryMoreViewHolder {
    TextView tv_name;
    TextView tv_location;
    LinearLayout ll;
}
```

But when I change the if condition like

```
 if (view == null || view.getTag(R.id.history_second_item) == null ||
     view.getTag(R.id.history_first_item) == null   )
```

I can get the holder back, can anyone tell me why?

The listview has not enough item to scorll, so it is not reuse problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because non-null `view` inside `getView` could be for another index (ListView can re-use old view to display new item), you should initialise it again like when `view == null`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I see is that you have 2 types of cell scenarios. As you know, these list-views reuse cells when you scroll.

For the first time, you will get a null value at

```
if (view == null  ) {
```

Where you will create a new cell, followed by creating a new view-holder for the scenario.

The problem arises when a cell of type `HistoryViewHolder` gets reused at an index for a `HistoryMoreViewHolder`.

Comment: My listview has not enough item to scorll.so it is not reuse problem

Comment: @kelvin1757 did you check that? how many items in your list and how many times getView gets called?